# How do I show only last crossover?

Tags: pine-script-v4

I have an indicator which does crossovers and cross unders. It's displayed as a background color.
Currently it displays all crosses.

With what pinescript can I edit it, so it will only show the last one?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use `show_last` parameter:

```
//@version=5
indicator("My Script", overlay=true)
sma = ta.sma(close, 14)
cond = ta.cross(close, sma)
bgcolor(cond ? color.teal : na, show_last=1)
```